# System Apps not opening in Mojave

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, time-machine, mojave, big-sur

I recently upgraded to macOS BigSur, but after that my mac started to lag.

By lag I mean the transitions while switching between apps using the trackpad were very slow and the trackpad used to respond after 1-2 seconds!

It was a horrible experience, so I decided to downgrade it. I have done it before also from Catalina to Mojave as there were many bugs in it.

But this time I restored the data using a time machine backup.....

It didn’t go well

This was my dock in BigSur[image]

Now, this is the dock in Mojave[image]

Can't open any app, I even tried searching for messages in the spotlight search, but there also it isn’t opening.

And now when I go to about this mac and then storage, it says 48 GB is used by the system, isn’t it too much!!

[image]

Is there any way?

I think the reinstalling will work but is there any other way coz the reinstallation takes a lot of time

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am using a MacBook Pro Mid 2018 13" with touchbar

Comment: "restored the data using a time machine backup" Knowing **precisely** what method you used to do this would be most helpful. You cannot overlay one one top of the other, you must do a complete format & replace. (The Time Machine backup must also never have seen Big Sur, or it will not be possible)

Comment: @Tetsujin i took the backup using time machine in a hard disk, took the mac in recovery mode, wiped the data and all partitions and then installed Mojave using a pen drive, and then while setting it up i choose to use the backup made by time machine to transfer the data

Comment: But **when** did you do the backup? Before you upgraded to Big Sur, or after? if you did it after, you can't use it to go back 'downhill'.

Comment: After, but like is there a way i can get my dock back to normal?

Comment: Clean install macOS. Re-download apps, then just copy back your documents from the backup. You might struggle with such as Mail, as the format keeps changing between OS versions.

Comment: Ohk! I just wanted to ask if there is any other way to do so

Comment: Not if your backup was from Big Sur. Remember for next time, you must take the Time Machine backup **before** the upgrade, then physically disconnect it from the Mac. Once a backup has 'seen' the new OS you can no longer go back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116432/discussion-between-manan-vyas-and-tetsujin).